# How to get Embedded object from Entity table?

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I use Java, Spring Boot and PostgreSQL.
So here's my 2 classes:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Entity
public class Entity {

  @Id
  private int id;
  @Embedded
  @ElementCollection
  private List<EmbeddedClass> embeddedObjects;
}
```

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
@ToString
@Embeddable
public class EmbeddedClass {
  private UUID userId;
  private UUID friendId;
  private int something;
}
```

My question is how to get an `EmbeddedClass` object from the `EntityRepository` which looks like this:

```
@Repository
public interface EntityRepository extends JpaRepository<Entity, UUID> {

  @Query(value = "SELECT user_id, friend_id, something FROM entity_embedded_objects", nativeQuery = true)
  Optional<EmbeddedClass> findEmbeddedObject();
}
```

And I get this error message now when I try this query:
`org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [java.lang.String] to type [EmbeddedClass]`

I tried different solutions, the best I could get is this error message, but I don't remember how:
`org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 1111; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 1111`

Comment: What does the query is supposed to do ? Find a specific embeddedObject ? Is that so, shouldn't there be a 'WHERE' clause somewhere ?

Comment: No, find all EmbeddedObject or just one. It's not the main part of my question. I could do a where clause.

Comment: That is why I made a comment and not a answer, to get some precision before being able to write a correct solution (For instance, in your example, the query does not match the method signature, the query suggest multiple values, but the signature only 1).

Comment: Okay, but it doesn't solve the problem sadly. The main part is to get an EmbeddedObject from columns in a table where Entities are being stored.